# Embedded Windows Media Player not streaming avi file?

Tags: asp-classic, embed, media-player

Hi I have a webpage that's using classic ASP that I want  to display a streaming video for the user to watch.

```
<OBJECT id='mediaPlayer' width="480" height="428" 
classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" standby="Loading Microsoft® Windows® Media       
Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject"                               
codebase="https://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112">    
<param name="fileName" value="VehiclePreOp.avi">  <param name="autoStart" value="True">  
<param name="showControls" value="true">  <param name="AllowChangeDisplaySize" value="true">  
<param name="ClickToPlay" value="true">  <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" 
pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="VehiclePreOp.avi" autoStart="True" >
</embed></OBJECT>
```

For some reason the video doesn't show and the screen is just black within the embedded player. Anyone have any ideas on why the video won't show?

O yes just using IE 8 and not FF or Chrome.

Comment: the avi file and the html file are in the same folder? have you tried another video file like a wmv?

Comment: The file is in d:\dev\Production\ATS\Presentations\VehiclePre\VehiclePreOp.avi The HTML is in \\Production\ATS Currently I don't have any tools to convert files but if it comes down to it I might just have to do that just to test

Comment: is the avi on your local machine and your html on a web server?  That won't work without copying your .avi file out to the same folder as the HTML.

Comment: they're both on the webserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the path name to the video file correct ?

Comment: Yea I double checked the path just to be sure. Does WMP have to be installed server side of the embed to work?

Comment: I tested your code and it does work for me.  Did you hit "Play" to start the video?

Comment: yea, going to convert the video into a few different formats and see if that works

Comment: I tested with .avi and .wmv - both worked.  the video has to be in the same folder as the ASP file or you need to provide the full physical pathname.

Comment: Thanks for testing, I appreciate it. Yeah I have the path: <param name="URL"value="d:\dev\Production\ATS\Presentations\VehiclePre\VehiclePreOp.wmv">  written out physically. I'll keep playing and trying especially with the IIS server

Comment: I tested in both FF and IE so it's definitely not your code.  Good hunting.

Comment: try using a web URL like "http://<servername>/VehiclePreOp.wmv" something like that might fix it.

Comment: Ok the way the folder is structured is that all the presentations and media files are in a subfolder seperate from the html file. The PPT and JPG file works fine but for some reason video doesn't so I stuck the video files with the html and change the code to: <param name="fileName"value=VehiclePreOp.avi > and also for SRC

Comment: Thanks Dee and Robert, I appreciate the help!