# PHP - Stream AVI-Videos

Tags: php, video, stream, movie, avi

on my website i will stream mpg/avi videos.

now i am looking for a videoplayer that supports that avi files.

does the JW-Flashplayer support that avi movie files or the adobe flash player?

**which videoplayers are available to show a avi movie via webbrowser?**

```
<body>
<OBJECT id=????? classid=????? ....>
</body>
```

Comment: I would take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733749/embedded-windows-media-player-not-streaming-avi-file). Also, out of curiousity, why *.avi?

Comment: JW-Flashplayer does not appear to support AVI files, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the media player that I used for avi files

```
    <object id="MediaPlayer1" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701 standby="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="480" height="456">
    <param name="fileName" value="<?php echo "attached/". $v1; ?>">
    <param name="animationatStart" value="true">
    <PARAM NAME="BufferingTime" VALUE="5">
    <PARAM NAME="BaseURL" VALUE="">
    <param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
    <param name="autoStart" value="true">
    <PARAM NAME="AllowChangeDisplaySize" VALUE="true">
    <param name="autorewind" value="true">
    <param name="showControls" value="true">
    <param name="Volume" value="-450">
    <param name="loop" value="true">
    <param name="PlayCount" value="100">        
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="<?php echo "attached/". $v1; ?>" name="MediaPlayer1" width=680 height=656 playcount=100 loop=1 autostart=1 showcontrols=1 volume=-450>
    </object>
```